# Synchronizing two or more Google Home devices

Tags: google-home

I want to have a setup where I can speak a command into one Google Home devices and have more than one devices respond at the same time.

For example:

I will have one Google Home device in my kitchen and another in my living room so if I tell the one in the kitchen something like "Play the song never gonna give you up by Rick Astley." ;) It will play on the Google Home device in the kitchen along with one in the living room.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Multi-room group playback is possible by grouping any combination of Google Home, Chromecast Audio devices, or speakers with Chromecast built-in together for synchronous music throughout the home.

You can create an audio group using the Google Home app, and control audio group using your voice. For a detailed step by step how to guide please visit [Multi-room group playback with Google Home](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7174267?hl=en).
You will need to follow the "Create and manage audio groups" sections and then you can go on to use the audio group.